# how to click a specific text in the page JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

after trying many ways to detect a specific word in the page and auto click on it ..so far i have

```js
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (items[0].textContent == "my text or word") {
        items[0].click();
    }
}
```

the latest code seems work only for the first time (one time) but after refresh nothing happened i dont know what wrong

Comment: Are you sure the element is loaded onto the page when you try to click it? Showing reproducible markup or a URL of the site seems needed. You might need a `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Also to throw a wrench in to the logic, if the textContent contains any leading or following spacing, that equality will not match anything

Comment: Also can initiate click on parent element if it has no text but children do. Really need a  [mcve] that displays the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I have mixed success with `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")`, so the below code uses either `document.all` OR `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")` depending on which is supported.

You were using `[0]` as your index when it should have been the variable `[i]`. Also, you can use the method `.includes` which will search for a substring (a string within a string), making it more likely you will find the element you are looking for. Just tested the below in firefox console and seems to work fine.

```
 if (document.all !== undefined)
    {
      var items = document.all;
    }
    else
    {
      var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    };                    
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (items[i].textContent.includes("Your Text Here")) {
            console.log("success"); 
            items[i].click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I STAR WORK FROM YOUR CODE AND SEEMS WORKS FINE  if (document.all !== undefined)
    {

      var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    };
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (items[i].textContent.includes("OTP")) {
            console.log("success");
            items[i].click();
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

You have items[0] in your for loop when it should be items[i], so it isn't iterating the condition or click.

```js
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (items[i].textContent == "my text") {
        items[i].click();
        console.log("clicked", i) 
    } else {
        console.log("loop",i)
    } 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>my text</div>
<div>my text</div>
<div></div>
```